# Django display different models/tabells

Tags: python, html, django

I get stuck. I try to display each time a other table in django with the same def in my view.py code.

First problem is I can't transfer the string which I enter in the url to a model. 
For example if I type 0.0.0.0:8000/polls/Cashflows I wanna display the table Cashflows of my db.

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import loader
from django.apps import apps
from .models import Cashflows,Garbage,Inputacturial


def index(request):
    list_cashflows=Cashflows.objects.all()
    template=loader.get_template('polls/index.html')
    context={'list_cashflows':list_cashflows,}
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context,request))

def detail(request, table):
    #model = apps.get_model('polls', 'table')
    #model=apps.get_model ( 'polls',table.split('.',1))
    model=Cashflows
    liste_column=model.objects.all()
    b=model._meta.get_fields()
    #b=a[:]
    liste_fields=list(b)
    template=loader.get_template('polls/index2.html')
    context={'liste_column':liste_column,'liste_fields':liste_fields,}
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context,request))
```

I try different options but none of these really work for.

My next problem is to display these different tables. 
I try to start with the field names.

```
<table>{% for item in liste_fields%}
    <tr><th>liste_fields.item</th>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

It's just give me three rows with liste.fields.item and not columns with each field. Can you help me?

Comment: 1. How does your `urls.py` look like?
2. You need to put variable name into double curly braces, and not to reference the array/list name in the for cycle. So just `<th>{{item}}</th>`.

Comment: urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('<str:table>/', views.detail, name='detail'),
    
]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have of use the o method `verbose_name`

For example:

`list_fields = [field.verbose_name for field in Cashflows._meta.get_fields() if not field.is_relation or field.one_to_one or (field.many_to_one and field.related_model)]`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/meta/#migrating-from-the-old-api